# How Do I Format A SharePoint 2010 Search Refiner Lookup

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, lookup-column, refiner

In SharePoint 2010 Search, I've added a new managed property that refers to a lookup column. I then added a custom refiner by modifying the Refinement Panel "Filter Category Definition". Basically, I followed the steps in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spnext/archive/2010/08/09/customising-sharepoint-2010-search-refiners.aspx.

The refinement is working just fine except the refiners appear with the lookup ID and the lookup text. Is there anyway to just display the text?

[image: Search Refiner Lookup]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer shortly after posting the question.

The credit goes to http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2008/10/05/how-to-crawl-lookup-field-or-column/:

> The solution is, just go back and edit your managed property mapping and instead of mapping Category; map ows_Category. This is an internal property generated by the Sharepoint when you created Category and this property saves the actual value.